# excel: динамическое изменение адреса ячейки (суммирование по вычисляемому адресу)

Tags: excel, excel-формулы, суммирование

Стоит задача так написать формулу сложения содержимого ячеек, чтобы адреса ячеек были не фиксированными, а вычислялись в зависимости от содержимого других ячеек.

Как это сделать?

Пример:

```
= СУММ(A1:A10)
= СУММ(A11:A20)
```

А я хочу что-то типа такого

```
= СУММ(A(B1*10 + 1):A(B1*10 + 10))
= СУММ(A(B2*10 + 1):A(B2*10 + 10))
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 =СУММ(СМЕЩ($A$1;B1*10;;10;1))
```

Ищем начало диапазона - смещаем ссылку с A1 вниз на B1*10. По столбцам смещения нет, задаем размер диапазона - 10 строк, 1 столбец. Суммируем значения полученного диапазона.

Формула простая, короткая и понятная, но имеет один большой недостаток. Функция *СМЕЩ* - одна из немногих летучих (volatile) - пересчитывается не только при изменении входных данных, но и при любых изменениях на листе, а это может стать причиной торможения вычислений.

Вариант немного сложнее, но лучше.

```
=СУММ(ИНДЕКС(A:A;B1*10+1):ИНДЕКС(A:A;B1*10+10))
```

Две функции указывают на начало и конец диапазона: со строки B1*10+1 до строки B1*10+10.

Такая формула частично летуча - она пересчитывается только при открытии книги (для определения динамического диапазона). В открытой книге пересчет происходит только при изменении входных данных.